# Boost Spirit how to pass a local reference as attribute

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

How can I pass _a as reference to a sub rule which has an attribute of the same type:

```
rule(_a)
```

does not work.

The code looks like:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, Mdlx(), qi::locals<std::string, long32>, Skipper> mdl; // parent rule
qi::rule<Iterator, Model(long32&), Skipper> model; // sub rule

...

mdl =
        -version[at_c<0>(_val) = _1]
        // wrong code! pass _b because it has the type long32
        //>> -model(_a)[at_c<1>(_val) = _1] // pass local as attribute
        >> -model(_b)[at_c<1>(_val) = _1] // pass local as attribute
        >> -sequences[at_c<2>(_val) = _1]
        >> -global_sequences[at_c<3>(_val) = _1]
        >> -textures[at_c<4>(_val) = _1]
        >> -materials[at_c<5>(_val) = _1]
        >> repeat(_a)[
            geoset_animation
        ]
    ;

model =
        lit("Model")
        >> string_literal[at_c<0>(_val) = _1]
        >> lit('{')
            >> -(
                lit("NumGeosetAnims")
                >> integer_literal[_r1 = _1] // assign the value to the passed attribute
                >> lit(',')
            )
            >> lit("BlendTime") >> integer_literal[at_c<1>(_val) = _1]
            >> lit(',')
            >> bounds[at_c<2>(_val) = _1]
        >> lit('}')
    ;
```

As you can see I want to pass a local as reference to the sub rule which should set the long32 value.
The value is then used in the parent rule as local variable _a.

**edit:**
I've found the error in my code. I was passing _a but the first local has type std::string. I had to pass _b instead!

Comment: The amount of useful code _not_ shown here is palpable. Can I humor you with a template, so that you can build a useful SSCCE from it? http://paste.ubuntu.com/9030001/

Comment: After even more deliberation: do you want to assign the attribute of a subrule to the local in the "parent" rule?

Comment: Exactly. The idea is to pass the local as reference. The attribute type is "int&" and the local type is "int". Passing the local as attribute should allow the sub rule to assign a value.

Comment: Oh. Aha. I fully expect we cannot even declare a local of type `qi::locals<int&>` (because, how would that be default constructed?). However, there is the _inherited attributes_ feature that seems close to what you want. I'll add it to my answer in a bit.

Comment: I've added some code. I hope this helps.

Comment: The alternative would be to store the count in the resulting value of the sub rule which in this case was not possible. Therefore I thought about passing it into the reference.

Comment: It might be a tad late now :) Yes, you should add this kind of code _before_ posting an answer really. I'm not the downvotey type, but the question as posed was really flimsy. I hope my answers helped though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the clarification of the question, I surmise that you are looking for a feature more like Spirit's **[Inherited Attributes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/abstracts/attributes/nonterminal_attributes.html)**. Most significantly, these are always passed at invocation, so they need not be default-constructible and can be reference types.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b80a5df88fadbe0)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It>
struct my_parser : qi::grammar<It> {
    my_parser() : my_parser::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;

        start                            = my_int_rule;
        my_int_rule                      = my_rule_with_inherited_attribute(_val);
        my_rule_with_inherited_attribute = int_ [ _r1 = _1 ]; // copied into the reference passed

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(my_rule_with_inherited_attribute)(my_int_rule))
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It> start;
    qi::rule<It, int() > my_int_rule;
    qi::rule<It, void(int&) > my_rule_with_inherited_attribute;
};

int main()
{
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    my_parser<It> p;

    std::string const input = "123";

    bool ok = qi::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), p);

    std::cout << "Parse " << (ok? "success":"failed") << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
<start>
  <try>123</try>
  <my_int_rule>
    <try>123</try>
    <my_rule_with_inherited_attribute>
      <try>123</try>
      <success></success>
      <attributes>[, 123]</attributes>
    </my_rule_with_inherited_attribute>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[123]</attributes>
  </my_int_rule>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</start>
Parse success
```

Comment: Is there no way to pass _a instead of _val?

Comment: Have I finally bordered on the real question? Lemme try it. Reporting back

Comment: This should be the valid reply. I've made a mistake by passing the wrong local, so it could not be compiled. Thx and sorry for the bad question but I did not know how to put it.

Comment: @Baradé Nevermind :) I was also messing up with all the versions of the rules I had lying about, but yeah, nothing prohibits it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5308e6d444e52eb3 (it shows how I was on a goose chase until I noticed that my third rule was just wrong :))

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I *guessed* what you actually meant here correctly:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83ba8fc425051e10)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It>
struct my_parser : qi::grammar<It> {
    my_parser() : my_parser::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;

        my_rule_with_a_local = my_int_rule [ _a = _1 ];
        my_int_rule          = int_; 

        start = my_rule_with_a_local;
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(my_rule_with_a_local)(my_int_rule))
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It> start;
    qi::rule<It, int() > my_int_rule;
    qi::rule<It, qi::locals<int> > my_rule_with_a_local;
};

int main()
{
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    my_parser<It> p;

    std::string const input = "123";

    bool ok = qi::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), p);

    std::cout << "Parse " << (ok? "success":"failed") << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
<start>
  <try>123</try>
  <my_rule_with_a_local>
    <try>123</try>
    <my_int_rule>
      <try>123</try>
      <success></success>
      <attributes>[123]</attributes>
    </my_int_rule>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[]</attributes><locals>(123)</locals>
  </my_rule_with_a_local>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</start>
```